# How to import external lib in h2 database while using runscript

Tags: h2

How to import external lib in h2 database while using runscript as I need to use Microsoft jdbc lib

Comment: You can't use the Microsoft JDBC driver to connect to an H2 database

Comment: I needed SqlServerDataTable function to create temp table